# Apply list of function to a seq in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a list of function, e.g `[f g h ..]` and list items with the same length `[a b c ..]`.

What's proper way to get result as: `[(f a) (g b) (h c) ..]` (apply each function to an item at the same position)

Comment: use map on two collections: `(map #(%1 %2) [inc dec zero?] [10 20 1])` => `(11 19 false)`

Comment: oh, cool, i never use map with 2 colls before

Comment: @leetwinski Did you post the solution as a comment instead of an answer to keep your sweet rep count intact for a bit longer? :P

Comment: @SamEstep, i believe this trivial answer doesn't deserve larger font size )).. oh Just noticed my rep! thanks for pointing

Comment: today i tried very hard to replicate @leetwinski 's success in reputation, and failed by one. ;-(

Comment: @leetwinski when people come along later, and ask the same question it's hard to mark those as duplicates of this if this one is "unanswered". hint hint nudge nudge..

Comment: @leetwinski - using `deliver` works well instead of the ad-hoc reader-function: `(map deliver [inc dec zero?] [10 20 1])`

Comment: @DaoWen That seems like abuse of an implementation detail to me.

Comment: @SamEstep - You're right... The documentation only mentions promises.